# How To Add Dependencies in Group Of Groups In XML of TestNG

Tags: xml, testng

How To Add Dependencies in Group Of Groups in XML of TestNG.This is my XML

```
<test name="Test1">

<classes>
  <class name="test.TestNGTest1"/>
  <class name="test.TestNGTest2"/>
  <groups>
      <define name="abc">
          <include name="a"></include>
      </define>
      <define name="def">
          <include name="b"></include>
      </define>
      <run>
          <include name="def"></include>
          <include name="abc"></include>
      </run>
  </groups>
</classes>
</test>
```

I try to add dependency group of groups on xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two test classes:

```
public class TestNGTest1 {
    @Test(groups = {"a"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(groups = {"b"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(groups = {"c"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(groups = {"d"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(groups = {"e"})
    public void test5(){}
    @Test(groups = {"f"})
    public void test6(){}
}
```

and

```
public class TestNGTest2 {
    @Test(groups = {"a"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(groups = {"b"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(groups = {"c"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(groups = {"a"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(groups = {"b"})
    public void test5(){}
    @Test(groups = {"c"})
    public void test6(){}
}
```

The dependency of group of groups could be defined in following way:

```
<suite>
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.TestNGTest1"/>
            <class name="test.TestNGTest2"/>
            <groups>
                <define name="abc">
                    <include name="a"></include>
                    <include name="b"></include>
                </define>
                <define name="def">
                    <include name="d"></include>
                    <include name="e"></include>
                </define>
                <dependencies>
                    <group name="abc" depends-on="def" />
                </dependencies>
                <run>
                    <include name="def"></include>
                    <include name="abc"></include>
                </run>
            </groups>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify group dependencies in xml by using depends on and dependencies tag eg [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml).

Comment: thanks for your help but I did not need this I ask how to add dependencies on group of group on xml.The link which you given it shows only add dependencies on single group.

Comment: @moin, group of groups is still a group, so the link provided is still applicable